# Is Bianca Castafiore actually a good singer?

Tags: tintin

**When Bianca Castafiore sings quietly, her notes are fine:**

[image]

Here's another example:

[image: Normal singing]

**In nearly every panel depicting Castafiore *performing*, however, the notes are drawn in a jarring and misshapen fashion:**

[image: Performance]

Here's another example:

[image]

**Is Bianca Castafiore actually a good performer?**

Comment: What is the source for the first image (the one with the information box in the lower right corner)? Depending on its canonicity, it could be an important hint, as both [Maria Callas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maria_Callas) and [Renata Tebaldi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renata_Tebaldi) were renowned for their beautiful _voice_, and they don't appear to be the inspiration for Bianca Castafiore's _look_.

Comment: A couple of additional details: Bianca Castafiore's first appearance is in _"King Ottokar's Sceptre"_ (1939), wich predates both Maria Callas' and Renata Tebaldi's debuts but not [Florence Foster Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florence_Foster_Jenkins)'s. The [Tintin wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Tintin#Supporting_characters) states Callas was an inspiration for the character _"in the post-war comics"_ (backed by a link to a paywalled article).

Comment: I think you're seeing Haddock/Tintin's interpretations of her singing. A lot of people don't appreciate opera and would probably depict it similarly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only my opinion as a longtime Tintin fan: Castafiore's performances are not off-key; it's the volume that assaults the listeners. Notice Tintin's necktie being blown as if by the wind, but it's the power of Castafiore's voice doing it.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable interpretation, especially given the other character's reactions when she is performing!

Comment: This seems consistent with her representation on the Tintín and the secret of the unicorn movie too.

Comment: Does any comic depict the public's reaction to Castafiore's performances? Her receiving loud applause would be a proof of her good singing, despite Tintin's and Haddock's not-really-delighted reactions.